# Erro: function 'crear' is not defined

Tags: javascript

Intento crear un texto en canvas pasandole el texto que usará el `fillText()` como parametro de la función desde un evento `onclick` en el documento HTML, pero me dice que la función `crear()` no esta definida.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
/* Dibujo canvas */

var c = document.getElementById("m");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');



function crear(texto) {
  
  ctx.fillText(texto,55,60);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ECECF9";
}
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="e" placeHolder="Texto a dibujar.."/>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="crear(document.getElementById('e').value)"/>
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="m"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por que la funcion **crear** no existe a nivel de la página; la estas creando solo para *load*; mira bien las aperturas de inicio y cierre de tu código.

Comment: El título no es descriptivo. No se incluye que es lo que esperas que haga el código. Véase [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No anda porque la función cerrar está dentro de la función del evento "load". Una solución fácil es sacar la función como global o asignársela al objeto windows (que también la hace disponible globalmente).

## Recomendación

### Mantener separado el código del HTML (siempre que sea posible).

En tu caso significaría asignar el comportamiento del evento `click` desde el código Javascript (para eso hay que asignar un ID al botón).

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    /* Dibujo canvas */

    var c = document.getElementById("m");
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

    //se define la función
    function crear(texto) {
        ctx.fillText(texto,55,60);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ECECF9";
    }
    // se asigna la función al botón
    document.getElementById('el-boton').addEventListener('click',function(){ 
        crear(document.getElementById('e').value);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="e" placeHolder="Texto a dibujar.."/>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="el-boton"/>
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="m"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Ventajas:

1. El HTML viaja sin código (es más seguro)
2. No hay necesidad de poner globales las funciones (y el código queda más ordenado)

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` espera que la funcion este en ambito global pero tu lo tienes en ambito local del evento `window.addEventListener("load", function(){})`

Intenta haciendo la funcion visible globalmente con window:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
/* Dibujo canvas */

var c = document.getElementById("m");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');



window.crear = function (texto) {
  
  ctx.fillText(texto,55,60);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ECECF9";
}
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="e" placeHolder="Texto a dibujar.."/>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="crear(document.getElementById('e').value)"/>
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="m"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es más fácil si divides un poco las tareas.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("m");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var texto;

function escribir(texto) {
  ctx.fillText(texto,55,60);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ECECF9";
}

function getText() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('e').value;
    escribir(texto);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="e" placeHolder="Texto a dibujar.."/>
  <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick='getText()'/>
  <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="m"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```